# I want to split string with "," but from 2nd comma(,)

Tags: c#

I want to split string with "," but from 2nd comma(,)

Comment: Those two are the same string.
Could you maybe tell us what variable type you were hoping to have the result stored in?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you encountering. This is not a place where people will simply get your job done.

Answer (score 2):

haven't tried it, but you will need something like this:

```
string pattern = "|\*,";            
string[] result = Regex.Split(before_split, pattern);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for skip first ',' & then split rest of the string by ',' then you can try following.

```
string before_split = "pune,mumbai|01234,delhi|65432,Bhopal|09231,jabalpur|0987765";

var firstPart = before_split.Substring(0, before_split.IndexOf(",", System.StringComparison.Ordinal));
var stringToProcess = before_split.Substring(before_split.IndexOf(",", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
var stringSegments = stringToProcess.Split(',');

Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",firstPart ,stringSegments[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < stringSegments.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(stringSegments[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the final result is on a List finalSplit

```
    string before_split = "pune,mumbai|01234,333,222,delhi|65432,Bhopal|09231,jabalpur|0987765";
    string[] split1 = before_split.Split(',');
    List<string> finalSplit = new List<string>();
    string aux = "";
    foreach (string s in split1)
    {
        if (s.IndexOf('|') == -1)
            aux = aux + s + ',';
        else
        {
            if (aux == "")
                aux = s;
            else
                aux = aux  + s;
            finalSplit.Add(aux);
            aux = "";
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you very much
but is it possible to write dynamic code for other conditions like:
"delhi|65432,pune,mumbai|01234,Bhopal|09231,jabalpur|0987765"


and result should be same as above

you can consider any number of permutation combination.

Comment: I dont understand what u mean, with permutations, Ive try in diferent forms and always the parse is correct value1,value2,..valueN|number

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
string before_split = "pune,mumbai|01234,delhi|65432,Bhopal|09231,123,jabalpur|0987765";

string buffer = "";
var parts = before_split.Split(',');
var lines = parts.Select(p =>
{
    if (p.Contains('|'))
    {
        var line = buffer == "" ? p : buffer + ',' + p;
        buffer = "";
        return line;
    }
    else
    {
        buffer = buffer == "" ? p : buffer + ',' + p;
        return null;
    }
}).Where(p => p != null).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
        Regex rex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z,]*[|]+[0-9]+");

        var result = rex.Matches("pune,mumbai|01234,delhi|65432,Bhopal|09231,jabalpur|0987765").Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var result =before_split.Split(',')
```